# How To Display One Value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

how do i display only andir values, with each value beside it.
[image]

```
cari = df.groupby(['Kecamatan','Kelurahan'])['No'].count().reset_index(
  name='Jumlah').sort_values(['Kecamatan','Jumlah'], ascending=[True,False])
cari.style.hide_index()
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

ext_val = df.loc[df['Kecamatan'] == 'Andir']
print(ext_val)
```